# Spring cloud data flow shell : Stuck on "The stream is being deployed"

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I successfully registered three apps named appSink, appSource and appProcessor as follows

```
dataflow:>app register --name appSource --type source --uri maven://com.example:source:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --force
Successfully registered application 'source:appSource'
dataflow:>app register --name appProcessor --type processor --uri maven://com.example:processor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --force
Successfully registered application 'processor:appProcessor'
dataflow:>app register --name appSink --type sink --uri maven://com.example:sink:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT --force
Successfully registered application 'sink:appSink'
dataflow:>app list
╔══════════╤═════════════╤════════╤════╗
║  source  │  processor  │  sink  │task║
╠══════════╪═════════════╪════════╪════╣
║appSource│appProcessor│appSink│    ║
╚══════════╧═════════════╧════════╧════╝
```

I then created and deployed a stream as follows:

```
dataflow:>stream create --name myStream --definition 'appSource | appProcessor | appSink’
Created new stream 'myStream'
dataflow:>stream deploy --name myStream
```

I get the message

```
Deployment request has been sent for stream 'myStream'
```

In the streams list I see

```
║myStream1  │source-app | processor-app | sink-app│The stream is being deployed.                                         ║
```

The deployment never finishes it seems. The data flow server logs are just stuck on this

```
o.s.c.d.spi.local.LocalAppDeployer       : Deploying app with deploymentId myStream1.source-app instance 0.
```

Why is my stream not deploying successfully?

Comment: am also facing the same issue , have you found any fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see any java processes running in your local (that correspond to the applications being deployed)?

You can try remote debugging your application deployment using the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_remote_debugging

You can also try inheriting the apps logging using

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_log_redirect

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this same problem. I inherited the logging as you suggested. The UI never moves off of Deploying status. There are no errors in the logs and my stream is working when I test it.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, so you should probably remove it. If you want to comment on the OP's question, please use comments for that. If you have a new question, then please post a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Add spring boot actuator dependency in your project, dataflow calls /health and /info to see if the app is deployed or not.